# in sas9.1 ,when i use "ods rtf" procedure with "proc report" procedure

Tags: sas, report, rtf, proc, ods

In sas 9.1 , I use "ods rtf" procedure with "proc report" procedure. When I use title statement, the title is always retractive. What I should do to solve the problem.

```
options nodate nonumber missing=" ";
ods escapechar="#";
ods rtf   file="c:\9.rtf" bodytitle ;
proc report data=forreport7 nowindows  headline headskip split="|";
columns sort group  a _name_ trtseqpn1 trtseqpn3 trt01pn2 trt01pn3        trtseqpn_1_34 prob_seqpn prob_01pn;
define sort / order order=internal  noprint;
define group / group "Characteristics"  width=20 center ;
define a /order order=internal noprint;
define _name_ / display  " " style(column)=[just=left] center width=20 ;
define Trtseqpn1 / display  center  width=20  "NPH|(N=&Trtseqpn1.)";
define Trtseqpn3 / display  center width=20 "LY_All|(N=&trtseqpn3.)";
define Trt01pn2 / display center  width=20 "LY_AM|(N=&trt01pn2.)";
define Trt01pn3 / display  center width=20 "LY_PM|(N=&Trt01pn3.)";
define trtseqpn_1_34 / display  center width=20  "Ttoal/(N=&trtseqpn13.)";
define prob_seqpn / display center width=20 "LY_All vs. NPH";
define prob_01pn / display center width=20 "LY_AM vs. LY_PM";
compute after group;
line "#{    }";
endcomp;
run;

title1 justify=left height=0.37 cm  font="Times New Roman"  
"Summary and Analysis of Patient Demographic and Baseline Characteristics"  
justify=right    "#{thispage} of #{lastpage}     ";
title2 justify=left height=0.37 cm  "All Randomized Patients" 
justify=right height=0.37 cm   "&systime. &sysdate9.     ";
title3 justify=left  "I2R-MC-BIAK" justify=right  "Production status: PDPM"; 

ods rtf close;
```

You can find the problem in my picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A09bG.jpg)

Comment: Format your code so it's readable. It's currently a jumbled mess and It's unclear what you're asking. Also, TITLE statements go BEFORE your procedure not after. That's how they work. And SAS 9.1 is ancient, upgrades are included in your license so upgrade.

Comment: And I looked up rettractive. I don't know what you mean and it doesn't seem to be the correct word?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that causes your problem.